# What can you say about two expressions with same reminder?

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

I am working on Integer factorization problem and I came to those two interesting expressions:

- $a,b,c,x$ are non negative integers
- $a,b < c$

$$\frac{ax + b}{c-x}$$ and $$\frac{ac + b}{c-x}$$

The interesting part about it, is that the division in both of the expressions provide the same reminder. I don't know if it happens for all the assignments or not, with the constants $a,b,c$ that I am working with it does! And my goal is to find such $x$ that will give me a reminder of 0.

Do you have any idea how can I use this knowledge about the reminder in order to achieve my goal?

Here are few examples where it happens.

- $\frac{59x + 100}{101 - x}$ has same reminder as $\frac{6059}{101 - x}$
- $\frac{74x + 21}{157 - x}$ has same reminder as $\frac{11639}{157 - x}$

Comment: $ac-ax=a(c-x)$, so of course they have the same remainder; the $b$ doesn't matter...

Comment: @symplectomorphic Sorry, I don'y understand. Can you please explain in more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to show that their remainders are the same is to show that their difference has no remainder:
$$\frac{ax+b}{c-x}-\frac{ac+b}{c-x} = \frac{ax-ac}{c-x} = -a\frac{c-x}{c-x} = -a$$

Comment: Why if their difference has not reminder their reminder will be the same?

Comment: $a = b$ if and only if $a-b = 0$.

Comment: Just to be sure: By reminder do you refer for the result of x module y?

Comment: I mean polynomial remainder.